# laravel request index can't list array Categorized

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.7

**Note: my question is not duplicate**

I have form in out of site and use `web api laravel 5.7`, now is send these parameters as post:

```
estate: "545345"
id_number: "43534545"
serial_number: "435435345"
type[code_id]: "45345345435"
type[company]: ""
type[country]: ""
type[maintenance_period]: ""
type[model]: "5435345435"
type[name]: "5345345345"
waranty[company_id]: "0"
waranty[duration]: ""
waranty[end]: ""
waranty[start]: ""
```

part of form:

```
<input type="text" name="estate" required="">
<input type="text" name="id_number" required="">
<input type="text" name="type[code_id]">
<input type="text" name="type[company]">
```

Now I want to get `type` and `waranty` array: same as for example:

```
$type = ['name' => 'test','company' => '...', 'model' => '...' ]
```

I try these codes:

```
$type = $request->input('type.*'); // NULL
and
$type = $request->input('type'); // NULL
and 
$type = Input::get('type'); // NULL
and
$in = $request->all();
$type = $in['type']; // NULL
AND
$request->get('type'); // NULL
AND
$request->post('type') // NULL
```

Doesn't work :( , only I can get single variable, by this method: (but I need array)

```
$in = $request->all();
$in['type[code_id]'] ;
```

And I test `type[][code_id]`,`type[][name]`,... in form but not work :(

My `axios` method:

```
serial = function (id) {
    var srl = $(id).serializeArray();
    var post = {};
    for (const k in srl) {
        let item = srl[k];
        post[item.name] = item.value;
    }
    return post;
}

axios.post(url, serial("#frm")).then(function (res) {// succs axios ;

     console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {// error axios ;
    console.log(err);
}); // end axios ;
```

What is the Laravel native solution ? for this problem ?

note: I can create an function for solve this problem but I need laravel native solution.

Comment: Did you try `$request->get('type');`

Comment: Then I think you must send type parameter as an array value. Then in Laravel you would be able to use it as an array

Comment: @RohitRasela Yes of curse :(

Comment: Did you try `$request->get('type');` with your input name `type[][code_id]`?

Comment: @RohitRasela Yes bro, i tested it but any result except `NULL`

Comment: @KeitelDOG I have form in out of site and use axios to send array what is your mind?

Comment: What about `$request->post('type');`?

Comment: `estate: "545345"`  is your js code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185293/discussion-between-rohit-rasela-and-a1gard).

Comment: @RohitRasela now check post it's NULL too. yes in the submited form.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the input part. It's ok. Forget about request get as it won't parse type in string. But try `$company = $request->input('type.company');` and it should work. I don't know yet a way to transform directly to array if you have not send a full array from js.

Comment: And be sure to add some console log before returning post variable so that you can be sure your `item.value` are not empty.

Comment: @KeitelDOG the $request->input('type.company')  result of is `NULL`, I'm sure. and I cant see any `item.key` value it's `item[key] = value`

Comment: I meant console log for this : `post[item.name] = item.value;` to check existence of values.

Comment: The [Laravel 5.7 Request Input Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input) state that `When working with forms that contain array inputs, use "dot" notation to access the arrays`. There is some hints, try them out.

Comment: @KeitelDOG I told you it's not work :-(

Comment: Then there must be some missing data in your input, I've used array input in Laravel, now I've switched to Laravel 5.6 and 5.7, it still working. And it's documented since old versions, maybe you should try to put them manually just to be sure like `<input type="text" name="type[company]" value="StackExchange" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handles arrays with this function:

```
function categorizedArray($array){
    $ret = [] ;
    $re = '/(.*)\[(.*)\]/U';
    foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
        preg_match_all($re, $i, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
        if ($matches == []){
            $ret[$i] = $value ;
        }else{
            $ret[$matches[0][1]][$matches[0][2]] = $value ;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

for exmp: ( We assume the function define as [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers) )

```
$all = categorizedArray($request->all());
```